# Get ETA of a point on MKRoute

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit

I am working on an application that gets directions via MKDirectionsRequest. I know that the MKRoute provides an ETA for the final destination.

I would like to get an ETA of any specific point along the route and not just the final destination.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to calculate this yourself.

You need to work out what percentage of the way along the route the point you are interested it is. You can then take the data which is this percentage from `departureDate` to `arrivalDate`.

Alternatively you can use the current speed and the distance to the point in question to work out how long it takes to get there.

If you want an even better estimate you can compare how long the user took to get to the current point and compare this to the estimated time to get there. This will give you a ratio by which you can adjust the future estimates.

You could also try a MKDirectionsRequest to the "point along the route" to get the ETA.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have any data about the user's speed at this point. As for the percentage, I can try. But the speed could change drastically depending on the route. I was looking for any accurate methods that return the ETA.

Comment: If the user is traveling the route, you can get the speed from the [CLLocation's speed](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/speed).

Comment: The user WILL BE traveling that route and I need to display some information before the user begins travel.

Comment: If you don't want to calculate it yourself you can try a MKDirectionsRequest to each "point along the route".

Comment: I will probably be doing that.. Thank you!